# how to test blocconsumer on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

i want to ask about unit test widget on flutter. i have a screen that only listen on previous screen, the code :

```
return BlocConsumer<MenuBloc, MenuState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
      if (state is MyScreenLoaded) {
        Map<String, dynamic> messageShow = jsonDecode(state.message);
        var messageContent = messageShow['message'];
        state.statusCode != '200'
            ? _showAlert(state.statusCode, messageContent)
            : _checkCertificate(state.statusCode, messageContent);
      }
    }, builder: (context, state) {
//return code here
}
```

on _showAlert method void have some widget pop up, how to test it? i have do testing like this. but not working :

```
testWidgets('test existing trivia when state MyScreenloaded success', (WidgetTester tester) async{
    Map<String, String> testMessage = {'message': 'this is test'};
    when(menuBloc.state).thenAnswer((realInvocation) => MyScreenLoaded(message: '200', statusCode: testMessage.toString()));

    await tester.pumpWidget(BlocProvider.value(value: registerBloc, child: triviaScreen,));
    expect(find.byKey(MyScreenKeys.successTrivia), findsWidgets);
    expect(find.byKey(MyScreenKeys.imageSuccessTrivia), findsWidgets);
  });
```

thank you anyway...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? My team has the exact same problem.

Comment: Ya, you should mock the bloc

Comment: Yea but how? We tried using `whenListen` and couldn’t get it to work

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/unit-testing-with-bloc-b94de9655d86

Comment: see https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/packages/flutter_bloc/test/bloc_consumer_test.dart (You have to use a "real" menuBloc calling emit() instead of a mock).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, we have the following code:

```
  return BlocConsumer(
    bloc: widget.simpleBloc,
    listener: (context, state) {
      if (state is SimpleAState) {
        widget.onListenerA('A');
      }
      if (state is SimpleBState) {
        widget.onListenerB('B');
      }
    },
```

Now we want to test it. So far there are two solutions here:

**whenListen**

This should be the simple one. However it would be applicable for `listener` only, it would not work for others (e.g. `buildWhen`, `builder`, etc). Please refer to this [github](https://github.com/imudita/bloc_consumer_test/blob/dev/test/when_listen_widget_test.dart) for more detail.

```
testWidgets('Test BlocConsumer with whenListen', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  final simpleBloc = MockSimpleBloc();
  String resultA = '';
  String resultB = '';
  whenListen(
    simpleBloc,
    Stream.fromIterable([
      SimpleAState(),
      SimpleBState(),
    ]),
    initialState: SimpleInitial(),
  );

  await tester.pumpWidget(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: WhenListenWidget(
          simpleBloc: simpleBloc,
          onListenerA: (res) => resultA = res,
          onListenerB: (res) => resultB = res,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  await tester.pump();
  expect(resultA, 'A');
  expect(resultB, 'B');
});
```

**GlobalKey**

Using `GlobalKey` as per sample codes below. Please refer to this [github](https://github.com/imudita/bloc_consumer_test/blob/dev/test/global_key_widget_test.dart) for more detail.

```
testWidgets('Test BlocConsumer with GlobalKey', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  final globalKey = GlobalKey<GlobalKeyWidgetState>();
  final simpleBloc = MockSimpleBloc();
  String resultA = '';
  String resultB = '';

  when(() => simpleBloc.state).thenAnswer((_) => SimpleInitial());
  await tester.pumpWidget(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GlobalKeyWidget(
          key: globalKey,
          simpleBloc: simpleBloc,
          onListenerA: (res) => resultA = res,
          onListenerB: (res) => resultB = res,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  await tester.pump();

  expect(resultA, '');
  expect(resultB, '');
  final context = globalKey.currentContext;
  globalKey.currentState?.blockListener(context, SimpleAState());
  expect(resultA, 'A');
  globalKey.currentState?.blockListener(context, SimpleBState());
  expect(resultB, 'B');
});
```

With GlobalKey option, you need to do the following steps:

1. Refactor the `StatfullWidget` state to public: `_GlobalKeyWidgetState` to `GlobalKeyWidgetState`.
2. Refactor the code under `listener:` into public function, so it could be called from unit testing

   ```
      return BlocConsumer(
        bloc: widget.simpleBloc,
        listener: blockListener,
        builder: (context, state) {
        .....
      }

      void blockListener(context, state) {
        if (state is SimpleAState) {
          widget.onListenerA('A');
        }
        if (state is SimpleBState) {
          widget.onListenerB('B');
        }
      }
   ```
3. Then on unit testing code, we defined `globalKey` variable.

   ```
      final globalKey = GlobalKey<GlobalKeyWidgetState>();
   ```
4. And pass it to the widget

   ```
      body: GlobalKeyWidget(
        key: globalKey,
   ```
5. Finally, after `tester.pump()`, we could call/test the `blockListener` function.

   ```
      globalKey.currentState?.blockListener(context, SimpleAState());
      expect(resultA, 'A');
   ```

There are so many steps here, however basically you can call/test any functions here. Or event the any variable, as long as they set as public.
For complete code, please refer to this [github](https://github.com/imudita/bloc_consumer_test/tree/dev).